# When verifying TensorFlow install numpy not found error

Tags: tensorflow

I successfully installed Tensorflow using pip.  I activated a virtualenv first.  When I tried the verification:

```py
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`

I verified I have numpy installed.  Version: 1.15.4

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed numpy in your virtualenv?